# Create session with Devise in web API on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to make a login system for my project using the devise, I chose to do for him, because this project will have access and http api.

For now I can register a User using the following method of Registration class:

```
def create
  if UserService.create_user(params[:username], params[:email])
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created
      return
    end
    render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    return
  end

  render json: "exit", status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

and that is the model of my User note that it has all the things that devise adds:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :schedules
end
```

my problem is in session the class because he can not find the include `Devise::InternalHelpers`:

```
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:create]
  include Devise::InternalHelpers

  before_filter :ensure_params_exist

  def create
    build_resource
    resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:email])
    return invalid_login_attempt unless resource

    if resource.valid_password?(password: params[:password])
      sign_in("user", resource)
      render(json: {success: true, auth_token: resource.auth_token, login: resource.email})
      return
    end
    invalid_login_attempt
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out(resource_name)
  end

  protected
    def ensure_params_exist
      return unless params[:email].blank?
      render(json: {success: false, message: "missing email parameter"}, status: 422)
      return unless params[:password].blank?
      render(json: {success: false, message: "missing password parameter"}, status: 422)
    end

    def invalid_login_attempt
      warden.custom_failure!
      render(json: {success: false, message: "Error with your login or password"}, status: 401)
    end

  private
    def create_params
      params.permit(:email, :password)
    end
end
```

Another problem is that by the time creates the User he is not generating the token, is as it should work?

Well this is my mistakes how to do this InternalHelpers for API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Devise::InternalHelpers` has been removed. You should include [Devise::Controllers::Helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb) instead:

```
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:create]
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
  ...
```